# Scipy for Python3.7 in docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, scipy

This is my 2nd day of trying to conquer this bug. I feel like the answer is so obvious.

The last error I couldn't fix during installation is

```
_configtest.c:1:24: fatal error: sys/endian.h: No such file or directory
```

Here is a full traceback https://gist.github.com/oduvan/4236e707e47b630ebae43f3d607f1eee

The way I get it

```
root@default:~# docker run --rm -it python:3.7.0a4 bash
root@0af10e68c5b7:/# apt-get update && \
>     apt-get -y install \
>         libblas-dev \
>         liblapack-dev \
>         libatlas-base-dev \
>         gfortran

root@0af10e68c5b7:/# pip install scipy
```

The same steps work for python:3.6 container without any exception.

Please give me a hint how can I fix it.

Thanks

Comment: fwiw i tried this and couldn't install numpy either

Comment: add `python-dev build-essential` to the list of packages to be installed

Comment: @chris numpy was installed from git `pip install git+https://github.com/numpy/numpy` but scipy shows the same error from git too

Comment: @Sathya didn't help. python-dev there is from Python2.7